# User friendly way to show overview page, and download pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, pdf

For a site with a form, I want to show an overview/thank you page, and offer a pdf confirmation for download. I tried several ways but I am still not happy with the results. I suppose it is not possible to return two requests in a Django view, therefore I want to include some javascript in the page.

Method 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.open("/media/4bb3da7dc9380b3.pdf",'_blank');
});
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that the popup blocker blocks the download.

Method 2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.location = "/media/4bb3da7dc9380b3.pdf";
});
```

This works well when a browser is not configured to show a pdf inline. The thank you page is shown, and the download dialog starts. However when the browser shows the pdf inline, the overview/thank you page won't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery Tool or plugin to show pdf in popup box..

http://wedesignpixel.com/useful-effective-jquery-lightbox-plugins/

Comment: Thank you...using a popup is the way to go for me. Strangely enough the popup blocker doesn't work here, so thats good for me.